# float action button is not changing layouts

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

im having an isue with a fab, i already tested it , and made a setOnClickListener, but when i click the button it doesnt trade from layout.

xml(from fab)

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/_40ssp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:id="@+id/fabBtnCreateNote"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18ssp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF5100"

        />
```

and here is the kotlin file, where the fab is declared.(the toast is just to test the fab)

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_view.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)

        launch{
            context?.let{

                var notes = NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().getAllNotes()
                recycler_view.adapter = NotesAdapter(notes)
            }
        }
       fabBtnCreateNote.setOnClickListener{
            replaceFragment(CreateNoteFragment.newInstance(),false)
            Toast.makeText(context,"A nota requer um Titulo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code doenst reproduce the problem, but, doesnt 'teste' supposed to be 'fabBtnCreateNote'?

Comment: ye on my code i have it right, but i forgot to change here, but still not working

Comment: debugging fabBtnCreateNote is null?

Comment: yes it is , when i debugg it doesnt do nothing